# How to make HTTP proxy to the VPN Tunnel?

Tags: centos, vpn, http-proxy, socat

I have a VPN tunnel running, where `test.google.com` = VPN HTTP server with IP `10.0.0.3`.

So I have `/etc/hosts` with DNS mapping `test.google.com` = `10.0.0.3` when I `ping test.google.com` it works.

Now externally I need to test HTTP access so I applied the following:

```
$ socat TCP-LISTEN:9999,fork,reuseaddr TCP:test.google.com
```

Now when I browse http://myserver.com:9999 then it fails.

```
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /stackoverflow/test has not been defined.    
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle myserver.com has not been defined.
IBM WebSphere Application Server
```

Comment: Websphere hasn't been configured to answer requests for myserver.com. You'll need a reverse proxy running on myserver.com.

Comment: Which reverse proxy? how do i do that reverse proxy using socat?

Comment: I don't think socat can serve as a reverse proxy.  If you don't know the meaning of a reverse proxy, please look it up.  I'm thinking of haproxy or nginx.